# Responsive html table

Tags: html, mobile, html-table

I've created a `HTML` table with following structure:

```
Title Text Title Text
Title Text Title Text
```

now, on mobile `(<768px)` it should change to:

```
Title Text
Title Text
Title Text
Title Text
```

Is this possible (preferably without jQuery)?

HTML (with Bootstrap)

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>Title Column 1</th>
    <td>Content Column 1</td>
    <th>itle Column 2</th>
    <td>Content Column 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Title Column 1</th>
    <td>Content Column 1</td>
    <th>itle Column 2</th>
    <td>Content Column 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: 2 table rows? could you provide some code?

Comment: do you mind using div?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You can find the code in my question now.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

```
.table{ width:100%;}
.table tr , .table th{
  float:left;
 }
```